# class modify via set/get methods

Tags: c++, class, constants

trying to modify object in the class via get/set methods. I can't understand how change value just only use get/set method.

expected output : "Output : 89".

actual output  : "Output : 0"

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class TestClass{
public:
    int getValue() const{
        return _value;
    }

    void setValue(int value) {
        _value = value;
    }

private:

    int _value;
};

class A{
public:
    TestClass getTestClass() const{
        return _testClass;
    }

    void setTestClass(TestClass testClass) {
        _testClass = testClass;
    }

private:
    TestClass _testClass;
};

int main()
{

    A a;

    a.getTestClass().setValue(89);

    cout<<"Output :"<<a.getTestClass().getValue();

}
```

Comment: Try `a.getTestClass();` followed by `a.setValue(89);` in main()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
TestClass getTestClass() const{
    return _testClass;
}
```

with

```
TestClass& getTestClass() {
    return _testClass;
}
```

You want to return a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) otherwise you are just returning a copy of the variable. But Keep in mind that returning a (non-const) reference to the member variables of a class is not a good design approach.

Some things:

- please don't use `using namespace std;` - read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) why.
- please don't name your variables `_testClass` - go with `m_testClass` instead. You can read [hear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) about the reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a copy of `_testClass`. So when you modify it with `setValue(89)`, nothing happens because you're only modifying a copy that is discarded at the end of the line. Instead, you should return a reference.

Change this here:

```
TestClass getTestClass() const{
```

To this:

```
TestClass &getTestClass() {
```

And you get the expected output.