# How to make that : Objet.getsObject().setssObject()

Tags: c++

This is my first question on this forum, and i expect this will not be a dummy one.

I searched the answer everywhere but can't find it.
Feel free to redirect me if the question is already answered somewhere.

How can i set a component of an object, into a bigger object ?

EDIT :

I will make a proper example if it's unclear,

BigObject.h

```
#include "Object.h"
Class BigObject {
private : 
 Object object
 int number
public 
BigObject(Object,int);
Object get_object();
void set_object(Object);
int get_number()
void set_number(int);
}
```

BigObject.cpp

```
#include "BigObject.cpp" 
BigObject::BigObject(Object a,int b){
set_Object(a); 
set_number(b);
};
Object BigObject::get_object(){ return this->object; };
void BigObject::set_object(Object a){ this->object = a};
int BigObject::get_number(){return this->number};
void BigObject::set_number(int b){this->number = b};
```

Object.h

```
#include <string>
Class Object {
    private : 
     int bidule;
     std::string machin;
    public :
    Object(int,std::string);
    int get_int();
    void set_int(int);
    std::string get_string()
    void set_string(std::string);
    }
```

Object.cpp

```
#include "Object.h"
using namespace std;
Object::Object(int a,string b){
set_int(a);
set_string(b);
};
int Object::get_int(){return this->bidule};
void Object::set_int(int a){this->bidule = a};
string Object::get_string(){return this->machin};
void Object::set_string(string a){ this->machin = a};
```

question :

This does not work 
if i do :

```
BigObject.getObject().set_string("Foo");
```

It is not saved

```
cout << BigObject.getObject().get_string() << endl;
```

Doesn"t give foo.
Why ?
How can i save it in my Big Object ?

Comment: This really depends on what `getObject` is and does (and returns!) as well as what `setComponent` is and does. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: "best practise" is to include a [mcve] in your question ;)

Comment: You need to accompany your question with a proper [mcve]. It's kinda unclear at the moment. Take the [tour] and consult the [ask] in the [help].

Comment: It is very unclear what you have already and what you need. Do you just want to know how to implement [method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158812/does-this-code-from-the-c-programming-language-4th-edition-section-36-3-6-ha)?

Comment: Does your `getObject` return a reference to the object, opposed to the copy of it?

Comment: As a possible hint (and educated ***guess***), you might want to learn more about *references*.

Comment: We also had [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54554898/class-modify-via-set-get-methods) asked today, which feels kinda related to me.

Comment: Well i'm sorry, i will edit it then to gives a better example.

Comment: Try including the definitions of `getObject`, `setObject`, `getComponent` and `setComponent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `BigObject.getObject()` returns an instance, which creates a copy of the object. So when you call `setComponent` you are actually setting it onto a copy of the object, which is why when you attempt to print it out, you don't see what you're expecting. You need to read up on references and pointers (preferably the smart type).

You could change the definition of `getObject` to return a reference easily enough:

```
class BigObject
{
public:
    Object& getObject();
    const Object& getObject() const;
    void setObject(const Object &other);
};
```

Comment: I was sure it had something to do with that but i can't manage to find the answer.. thanks Senpaï :D

Comment: Also can you tell me the name of what you're doing, or a reference where i can find it ? i can't manage to find what should i type in the cpp file..

Comment: @CreatorOfMoon if you Google for 'C++ references' you'll find plenty of stuff about it. Technical information is available here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference
That's assuming you are interested in references, and not smart pointers (normally you'll use a mix of both).

Comment: Thank you a lot, it's amazing, i learned C++ in school but i never heard of that O_o. Have a nice day

Comment: @CreatorOfMoon "_i learned C++ in school but i never heard of that_" Then, I doubt that you learned C++. Sure, the course might have been _called_ C++, but you might have been actually taught "C with classes".

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Ahah, you're probably right !